# ng-repeat not reflecting when the source variable gets modified

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I have the following angularJs code. When my source data changes, my ng-repeat does not update my view. I looked at other posts and added `$scope.$apply();` , `$scope.$digest();` at the end of my ajax success callback, but it did not help. The idea is that the page will have an empty table in the begining and after the ajax call onReady() it will populate the rows with data. Could someone point me at what I am missing here or a better way to achieve the same

**JS:**

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module("jmeter-module", []);
    app.controller('JmeterTableController', ['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.data = [];
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var url = "jmeterTableData.html";
            fetchTableData(url, 10, 25);
        });

        function fetchTableData(url, minAge,  maxAge){
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: url,
                data: { minAge : minAge,
                    maxAge : maxAge },
                datatype: "json",
                success: function(data){
                    /*If I try to print data here, I see the values rightly getting returned*/
                    $scope.data = data;
                },
                error: function(e){
                    console.log(e);
                }
            });
        }
    }]);

})();
```

JSP:

```
<div id="buildGroupsParentDivId" ng-controller="JmeterTableController as row">
.
.
.
<tbody id="jmeter-table-content"    >
            <tr ng-repeat="val in row.data">
                  <td><img title="History" src="/images/history.png" width="20" height="20"></td>
                  <td><input type="checkbox" value="save"></td>
                  <td>{{val.firstName}}</td>
                  <td>{{val.lastResult}}</td>                      
                </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is with the execution of $.ajax outside of the scope of Angular's digest cycle. You could get this working with $scope.$apply, but since you're already using Angular it's better to use the AngularJS xhr helper methods:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

```
// Simple GET request example :
$http.get('/someUrl').
  then(function(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

Comment: Unless you have a very good reason to do a simple http request via ajax, this is the right answer =)

Comment: one more thing, you could also switch to using the angular.element(document).ready() function if you really need to call a function on document ready, but the provided example code doesn't need to be wrapped in this way. Just define your app & controller and let Angular kick into action when it knows the document is ready. e.g. http://plnkr.co/edit/6a6TSR?p=preview